# viewing other users on a unix box, can't this be prevented?

Tags: linux, security

I had a shared account at a very popular hosting company in the past that allowed shell (ssh) access into the server.

I found it interesting that I could traverse the file system and list all the users who were on the system.  User accounts usually matched the domain name.

Could they have not prevented this or is listing other users something that can't be locked down on a linux box?

Answer (score 4):

It is going to be very difficult to stop someone who knows what they are doing from gaining this information (I think /etc/passwd probably always needs to be accessible?).  Lots of shared hosting companies do at least make it so you can't list `/home` though.

If you really want this level of privacy at an affordable price, I recommend looking into getting a Virtual Private Server (VPS).

Answer (score 0):

They could simply disallow directory listing with a simple chmod.

But - as Kyle says - go for VPS if you are conserned with security. I would personally NEVER put anything valuable or production material on a server where regular users have console access.

Comment: Well, 4096 bit PGP encrypted files are probably okay, with the private key not on the server a good passphrase.

Comment: Not exactly a common scenario there Kyle, but I get your point.